# Overwriting value of a key in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to store a value in a Helper file, which is calculated after the initial require of the Helper, and the value doesn't change from undefined (because it was unknown to start with).

Is there any way I can overwrite this value to use elsewhere?

helper.js:

```
module.exports = {
    key:value
}
```

setup.js:

```
var helper = require("./helper.js");

... // hit a url and get a value
helper.key = newValue;
```

usage.js:

```
var helper = require("./helper.js");

console.log(helper.value) // prints the original value
```

**Flow**

```
setup.js -requires-> helper.js
usage.js -requires-> helper.js
```

I've read that module.exports is seemingly read-only, but surely there must be a way to do this.

Also, is it possible to add to module.exports after the initial creation?

```
module.exports["key"] = value;
```

Thanks in advance, seems like it should be simple but it's a roadblock for me.

**EDIT:** Ignore the second question, I have gotten this work (about the `module.exports["key"]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is an issue here. May be I don't understand the loading flow and there is some crazy scope configuration...

You can do it like this and you can alter the exports (whether this is a feature, is a different matter).

Imagine these modules:

**test1.js**

```
module.exports = {
    a: '1'
}
```

**test2.js**

```
var test1 = require('./test1');

module.exports = function() {
    test1.a = test1.a + '2';
    test1.b = 100;
};
```

**test3.js**

```
var test1 = require('./test1');

module.exports = function() {
    test1.a = test1.a + '3';
    test1.b = 200;
};
```

**test4.js**

```
var test2 = require('./test2')();
var test3 = require('./test3')();
var test1 = require('./test1');

console.log(test1);
```

The output, when running `node test4` is:

```
{ a: '123', b: 200 }
```

or, *if you switched the order of loading of modules 2 and 3 in module 4*:

```
var test2 = require('./test3')();
var test3 = require('./test2')();
var test1 = require('./test1');

console.log(test1);
```

it would become:

```
{ a: '132', b: 100 }
```

Comment: This is what I expected, but for some reason it seems to not be overwriting the value in the helper.

Comment: I've tested just now. Are you sure the configuration of your modules loading is the same?

Comment: One sec, let me take a look at it again

Comment: Is it significant you're changing the values from within module.exports in test2/3.js?

Comment: Nope. Would net the same exact result - **output wise** (granted, you'd not have to *invoke* the modules in *test4*.

Comment: So you're saying if I require my helper, and do `helper.key = newValue` it should work?

Comment: Well, if the above fits you... I am not sure how it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43090/discussion-between-zackehh9lives-and-zenmaster)